# Unable to remove objects from array , react.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to remove an item from a `childArray` that is nested into another Array.

This is How I'm trying.

```
const childArrayHandler = (childData, sub, questionId, data, btnId) => {
    // Manage color change on click
    const isInList = selectedBtnList.some((item) => item === btnId)
    if (isInList) {
      onSelectedBtnListChange(selectedBtnList.filter((item) => item !== btnId))
    } else {
      onSelectedBtnListChange([...selectedBtnList, btnId])
    }

    // Manage childData Array 
    // copy data to mutable object
    const currentChildData = [...childData]
    const hasId = currentChildData.find(({ id }) => sub.id === id)

    if (!hasId) {
      // add item to childArray if same index is not available in the childArray
      const newChild = { id: sub.id, sub_question: sub.sub_question, weightage: sub.weightage }
      currentChildData.push(newChild)
      setChildDataOnChange((current) => [...current, newChild])
    } else if (hasId) {
      // remove item from childArray if same index is available in the childArray
      const indexOfChild = currentChildData.indexOf(hasId)
      // console.log('currentChildData', currentChildData, 'indexOfChild', indexOfChild)
      currentChildData.slice(indexOfChild, 1)
      setChildDataOnChange(currentChildData)
    }

    const newData = [...data]

    // find parent of the child
    const parent = newData.find(({ parentId }) => questionId === parentId)

    // find index of parent
    const indexOfParent = newData.indexOf(parent)
    // update data with child related to parent
    newData[indexOfParent].child = currentChildData
    onDataChange(newData)
    localStorage.setItem('deviceReport', JSON.stringify(newData))
  }
```

The problem is in the `else if` block, I want if there's an index of object available in the child then it should remove it from the array. As far as I can see I'm using the correct approach as other articles suggested to handle but missing something which I cant see right now. But not able to find the proper result. If I console it doesn't change anything. means don't remove any item from the array if the index is already is there.

**So how can I fix this, or what might be doing wrong, is there any other way to do it please also mention it?** Thanks

Comment: `console.log('currentChildData', currentChildData, 'indexOfChild', indexOfChild)` which value did you get here?

Comment: I get expected results like currentChildData (2) [{…}, {…}] indexOfChild 0

Comment: you have expected `currentChildData`, but `setChildDataOnChange(currentChildData)` does not affect?

Comment: Yes currentChildData is making a copy of childData and currentChildData  should have been updated when I setChildData using setChildDataOnChange

Comment: You can modify your slice like  `currentChildData = currentChildData.slice(indexOfChild, 1)` and `setChildDataOnChange([...currentChildData])`. It's kind of reluctant but you can give it a try

Comment: You also can try to have a deep copy of `currentChildData` with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(currentChildData))`. It's not best practice, but at least we can narrow down where the problem is

Comment: uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable. , by doing your first suggestion

Comment: Convert this `const currentChildData = [...childData]` from `const` to `let`

Comment: **A)** It is unnecessary for `else if (hasId)` when the previous condition is `if (!hasId)`. If `hasId` is `falsy`, the `if` would have executed. No need to again check. **B)** At this line: `currentChildData.slice(indexOfChild, 1)` - you expect `currentChildData` to be changed, right? Please [read documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) for `.slice()` method. Does it mutate the array? Hint: The last statement in the first-paragraph: **`The original array will not be modified.`**

Comment: `slice` is not the case because s/he has been copying the array `const currentChildData = [...childData]` here, @jsN00b

Comment: If you are absolutely intentional on mutating, try with `.splice()` (although, I personally avoid mutating). Otherwise, use `.filter()` to remove the item at the index. Try: `setChildDataOnChange([...currentChildData.filter((ob, idx) => idx !== hasId)]);`

Comment: @NickVu Yes this works somehow but there's a catch, It doesn't update the state in real time, If I go to the next object then it updates the state. of data which is in the Array

Comment: @NickVu Thanks, One more thing with your approach all other child objects are also get removed that were not intended. , means it doesn't only remove the object that was in the array but also the other available objects

Comment: @jsN00b I think it has some hidden changes behind this. I was trying to guess around those changes without running code, but you're right about that `slice` is the problem in this piece of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the problem with this slice

```
currentChildData.slice(indexOfChild, 1)
```

It does not initialize a new array for you ([React's immutability](https://danburzo.github.io/react-recipes/recipes/immutability.html))

The fix could be

```
currentChildData = currentChildData.slice(0, indexOfChild).concat(currentChildData.slice(indexOfChild + 1))
```

If you feel it's too complicating, you can use `filter` instead

```
currentChildData = currentChildData.filter((item) => item !== hasId) //`hasId` is your found item with `find`
```

The 2nd problem here is

```
newData[indexOfParent].child = currentChildData
```

You cannot assign a value to a mutate object

The proper way should be

```
newData = newData.map((item) => item === parent ? {...item, child: currentChildData} : item)
```

The full code

```
const childArrayHandler = (childData, sub, questionId, data, btnId) => {
    // Manage color change on click
    const isInList = selectedBtnList.some((item) => item === btnId)
    if (isInList) {
      onSelectedBtnListChange(selectedBtnList.filter((item) => item !== btnId))
    } else {
      onSelectedBtnListChange([...selectedBtnList, btnId])
    }

    // Manage childData Array 
    // copy data to mutable object
    let currentChildData = [...childData]
    const hasId = currentChildData.find(({ id }) => sub.id === id)

    if (!hasId) {
      // add item to childArray if same index is not available in the childArray
      const newChild = { id: sub.id, sub_question: sub.sub_question, weightage: sub.weightage }
      currentChildData.push(newChild)
      setChildDataOnChange((current) => [...current, newChild])
    } else  {
      // console.log('currentChildData', currentChildData, 'indexOfChild', indexOfChild)
      currentChildData = currentChildData.filter((item) => item !== hasId)
      setChildDataOnChange(currentChildData)
    }

    //let newData = [...data]

    // find parent of the child
    //const parent = newData.find(({ parentId }) => questionId === parentId)

    // update data with child related to parent
    //newData = newData.map((item) => item === parent ? {...item, child: currentChildData} : item)

    //shorter version
    const newData = data.map((item) => item.parentId === questionId ? {...item, child: currentChildData} : item)
    
    onDataChange(newData)
    localStorage.setItem('deviceReport', JSON.stringify(newData))
  }
```